# self hosting wcf service

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

I am still a newbie in learning `wcf`. I have hosted a service in `console application(self host)`.

My base address is `http://localhost:8080/pulse`

How can some one else access this service from their system within the same network??

Will merely substituting `localhost` to my `ip address` work?

That is `http://171.220.14.7:8080/pulse`. Will this work? Can the `wsdl` be accessed through this?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: lack of infrastructure...and i have only used iis hosting so far. this is the first time i am self hosting a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this will work.

Obviously, you need to take care of all the normal things that can hinder people accessing your PC, like firewalls, network routing etc. But if they can access your PC, they can access the service the way you mentioned.

Comment: wouldn't the port number create an issue? that was the thought i had, cuz in `iis` we dont get the port number.

Comment: The port in IIS probably is 80 so it's default and doesn't have to be specified in browsers, but actually specifying a port is not a problem.